# I want to embed OneNote notebook into my website for interactive experience

Tags: website, onedrive, microsoft-onenote, sharepoint, embedded

So basicaly I want this eperience:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM1rP.png)

But the thing is I don't have SharePoint included in my subscription and I want to know if there is any other way to achieve this.

Here's the procedure of embeding it with SharePoint: [Link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Embed-your-Excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-SharePoint-or-OneDrive-for-Business-7af74ce6-e8a0-48ac-ba3b-a1dd627b7773)

Also if it was possible with OneDrive that would be great too, but I can't see any solution. I've been working on this all day.. please send help :x

Answer (score 1):

Found some information that might be the sad reality of the answer.
As I read the [Support article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/share-a-page-of-notes-or-an-entire-notebook-from-onenote-for-windows-10-d4a74a14-44a3-411e-8fb5-06e73ddf047f) it's said that's not really possible anymore or so I understand it is currently under development. Unfortunately not available at the moment.